# How do I make a batch file that started a process to wait for the process to terminate?

Tags: windows-7, batch, process, gaming, themes

My computer isn't the best but it does meet the minimal requirments to play [GTA V](http://store.steampowered.com/app/271590/). I wanted to make the game run faster so instead of using the normal .exe, this is the batch file I use to launch the game:

```
start steam://rungameid/271590 
timeout 60
wmic process where name="GTA5.exe" CALL setpriority "high priority"
wmic process where name="gtavlauncher.exe" CALL setpriority "idle"
wmic process where name="subprocess.exe" CALL setpriority "idle"
```

so basically after launching the game it sets the priorities so only the GTA5.exe runs and the cpu ignores the other processes that come with it.
I wanted it to run even smoother and changing the windows theme to "classic" helps with that, so I downloaded a [program](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-change-a-windows-theme-from-the-command-prompt/) that allowes me to change the themes with cmd commands and I made this script-

```
START c:\ThemeSwitcher classic
start steam://rungameid/271590 
timeout 60
wmic process where name="GTA5.exe" CALL setpriority "high priority"
wmic process where name="gtavlauncher.exe" CALL setpriority "idle"
wmic process where name="subprocess.exe" CALL setpriority "idle"
wait process where name="GTA5.exe" 
-----------------------------------------------------------
start c:\ThemeSwitcher MY PC
```

in the "----------" I want to put something that makes the file wait for the processes to terminate before changing the theme to normal, so I don't have to do it manually.
I only know a few batch commands that I used google for, and right now it doesn't help. 
sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create batch like this:

```
title i'm waiting
start /wait /high cmd /ktitle kill me 
echo This is the end 
pause
```

you can see how work `start` command with `wait` parameter

you can create batch with `pause`, after do something hit space in batch window, then it run next command

you probably looking for something like `waiting for terminate existing process`:

```
echo do somthing at start
:start_test
::wait ~6s -1s = 5s
::you can use TIMEOUT 5
call :sleep 6
wmic process where name="notepad.exe" get name |find "notepad.exe">nul
if %errorlevel%==0 goto :start_test
echo do somthing at the end
::pause
goto :eof

:sleep
ping 127.0.0.1 -n %1 > nul
goto :eof
```

it test process exists every 5s, you can change interval.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that only launches one new process is to use PowerShell!

You can find a process by name with the `Get-Process` cmdlet. Each process object has a `WaitForExit` method that, as can be expected, blocks until that process stops. Therefore, this PowerShell command will hang until `GTA5.exe`, `gtavlauncher.exe`, and `subprocess.exe` exit:

```
Get-Process 'gta5', 'gtavlauncher', 'subprocess' | % {$_.WaitForExit()}
```

This finds all processes with those names and waits for each to exit. The prompt won't come back until they're all gone.

You can use this to block a batch script by launching PowerShell giving that command (I've shortened it a little by using an alias):

```
powershell -command "gps 'gta5','gtavlauncher','subprocess'|%{$_.WaitForExit()}"
```

Once the processes exit, PowerShell will exit and return control to your batch script.